# Variable gets deleted after calling a function, Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a real-time chat app that uses firebase.

In the app you authenticate, and then you will be in a view controller that is the channels list, when you click on the channel you will be in the desired chat window. My code looks like this:

For the channel view controller:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

enum Section:Int {
   case createNewChannelSection = 0
   case currentChannelSection
}

class channelsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties
    var senderDisplayName: String? // 1
    var newChannelTextField: UITextField? // 2
    private var channels: [Channel] = []

    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
    // 1
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    // 2
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let currentSection: Section = Section(rawValue: section) {
            switch currentSection {
            case .createNewChannelSection:
                return 1
            case .currentChannelSection:
                return channels.count
            }
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    // 3
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let reuseIdentifier = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == Section.createNewChannelSection.rawValue ? "NewChannel" : "ExistingChannel"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section ==  Section.createNewChannelSection.rawValue {
            if let createNewChannelCell = cell as? CreateChannelCell {
                newChannelTextField = createNewChannelCell.newChannelNameField
            }
        } else if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == Section.currentChannelSection.rawValue {
            cell.textLabel?.text = channels[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].name
        }

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - UITableViewDelegate
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.section == Section.currentChannelSection.rawValue {
            let channel = channels[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
            print("perform segue")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowChannel", sender: channel)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Firebase related methods
    private lazy var channelRef: DatabaseReference = Database.database().reference().child("channels")
    private var channelRefHandle: DatabaseHandle?
    func observeChannels() {
        channelRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in // 1
            let channelData = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] // 2
            let id = snapshot.key
            if let name = channelData?["name"] as! String!, name.characters.count > 0 { // 3
                self.channels.append(Channel(id: id, name: name))
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            } else {
                print("Error! Could not decode channel data")
            }
        })
    }

    // MARK: - View Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Channels"
        observeChannels()
    }

    // MARK: - Actions
    @IBAction func createChannel(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if let name = newChannelTextField?.text {
            let newChannelRef = channelRef.childByAutoId()
            let channelItem = [
                "name" : name
            ]
            newChannelRef.setValue(channelItem)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

        if let channel = sender as? Channel {
            let chatVC = segue.destination as! ChatViewController

            chatVC.channel = channel
            print("\(channel)")
            chatVC.channelRef = channelRef.child(channel.id)
            print("id: \(channel.id)")
            print("\(chatVC.channelRef)")
        }
    }
}
```

For my chat view controller:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class ChatViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    // MARK: - Properties
    var channelRef: DatabaseReference?
    var channel: Channel? {
        didSet {
            title = channel?.name
        }
    }
    var messages = [Message]()
    @IBOutlet var TableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var messageBox: UITextField!

    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        TableView.delegate = self
        TableView.dataSource = self
        self.messageBox.delegate = self
        print("chat key: \(String(describing: channelRef?.key))")
        observeMessages()
    }

    // MARK: - Hide text field

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return false
    }

    // MARK: - Source Data
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        if messages.count > 0 {
            let message = messages[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = message.message
        }
        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - Firebase related methods
    private lazy var messageRef: DatabaseReference = self.channelRef!.child("messages")
    private var newMessageHandle: DatabaseHandle?
    func observeMessages() {
        print("observe called")
        messageRef = channelRef!.child("messages")// Error: force unwrapping nil value
        let messageQuery = messageRef.queryLimited(toLast:25)

       newMessageHandle = messageQuery.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
            // 3
            let messageData = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]

            let text = Message()
            text.setValuesForKeys(messageData!)
            self.messages.insert(text, at: 0)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.TableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }

    // MARK: - Actions
    @IBAction func Post(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let msg: [String: AnyObject] = ["message": messageBox.text as AnyObject]
        let dbRef = messageRef.childByAutoId()
        dbRef.setValue(msg)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

This is my console outputs:

```
perform segue
LearnFirebase.Channel // print("\(channel)")
id: -KvnLy92pj5czfGeA44p // print("id: \(channel.id)")
Optional(https://learnfirebase-2a4a6.firebaseio.com/channels/-KvnLy92pj5czfGeA44p) // print("\(chatVC.channelRef)")
chat key: nil // print("chat key: \(String(describing: channelRef?.key))") on the ChatViewController
observe called
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-10-10 10:18:09.146968+0300 fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Of course, there will be a crash, because I'm force unwrapping a nil object, but why is it nil? How can I fix this?

Thank you for answers.

Comment: Can you check if the performSegue in channelsTableViewController is being called twice for some reason? Maybe a print statement right before the performSegue to see if it's printed twice (once before each "chat key: (channel id)" message?

Comment: @RPatel99 I wrote: print("perform segue") right above the self.performSegue() call. It prints "perform segue" once and prints the prepareForSegue() twice.

Comment: @RPatel99 I did it again and I got: "perform segue" once, prepareForSegue() once with correct parameters, and chat key once but it's nil. do you know what's the problem?

Comment: So when you click a channel, does the console say `chat key: nil` and then `observe called` and that's it? Or is `chat key` printed twice, once with the channel ID and once with `nil` with `observe called` once after each `chat key`?

Comment: The console says `perform segue`, `id: -KvnLy92pj5czfGeA44p`(which I'm printing in the prepareForSegue()), `chat key: nil` and `observe called`.

Comment: What does the `print("\(chatVC.channelRef)")` in the prepareForSegue function print? Can you update your question to include the logs for all your print statements and also update your question based on what you said above (about how it only prints `chat key: nil` and then `observe` instead of both of the log snippets you provided in your question)?

Comment: @RPatel99 it prints: `https://learnfirebase-2a4a6.firebaseio.com/channels/-KvnLy92pj5czfGeA44p`

Comment: I'm assuming if you change `print("chat key: \(String(describing: channelRef?.key))")` to `print("\(channelRef)")`, it still says it is `nil`? If so, I'm not sure what's going on... you seem to have done everything right so it might be something not shown in the code that is causing the problem... Let me know if `print("\(channelRef?)")` prints something other than `nil`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156390/discussion-between-a-inbar-and-rpatel99).

Comment: I got `nil`. But I have interesting point, I changed:  `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` to: `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath?` with same code but return indexPath at the end.
The console outputs: 
perform segue 
LearnFirebase.Channel 
id: -KvnLy92pj5czfGeA44p 
Optional(learnfirebase-2a4a6.firebasei…) 
chat key: Optional("-KvnLy92pj5czfGeA44p") 
observe called 
chat key: nil 
observe called